# No puedo instalar visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

Hace unas semanas instalé VS2012, pero como ya no lo necesito, quiero desinstalarlo e instalar VS2015, pero no puedo, ni desinstalar VS2012 ni instalar VS2015. Me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Error que muestra al momento de instalar]

Que creen que pueda ser?. Alguna sugerencia...

Comment: Llegado a este punto ya desinstalaste VS2012?, si es así intenta limpiando los archivos temporales y verifica que la versión que estas ejecutando sea compatible con tu máquina (32 o 64 Bits)

Comment: No desinstala aún VS2012. Ya intenté limpiando los archivos temporales, incluso usando CCleaner. La versión de VS2015 es 64bits

Comment: intenta deinstalando VS2012 primero, si no descarga nuevamente el instalador, a lo mejor y esta dañado

Answer (score 0):

Dale una pasada al disco duro con `chkdsk /f` desde el `Command Prompt` y si aún así no funciona, intenta con `chkdsk /r` es probable que tu disco duro ande con sectores dañados donde está el instalador del VisualStudio. Más información en https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872425.aspx

Comment: Ok, lo intentaré, gracias!

Comment: de nada brother, estamos para servir :D

Answer (score 0):

Echa un vistazo a [desinstalacion vs 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2771441/how-to-uninstall-visual-studio-2012#Force). Te indican la forma automática y otra por linea de comados que te podría funcionar.